# How can i set up an API relay between my Google Apps Script API and my esendex.com push notifier

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, api-design

I am using esendex for handling inbound and outbound SMS http://developers.esendex.com/APIs/Push-Notifications

I am using Google apps script (GAS) to set up my message processing, the GAS api set up is here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run

My problem is the format/structure of the push notification is not compatible with the format/structure of the GAS api

My question is can I , and if i can how do I , set up a relay in the middle that will accept the push notification from esendex, reformat it and forward it to GAS and vice versa with the response code

Comment: Have you tried to publish your script as a webapp and set its url instead of Apps Script execution api?

Comment: No I haven't, Will the web app accept the xml object from the push notifier?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't ever tried this.

Comment: Thanks anyway Henrique

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running up against the limitations of a platform like GAS.

You could perhaps use something like Amazon API Gateway to transform the request and forward it on to GAS: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks like what i am looking for

Comment: you can use any api gateway...another one is APIGEE.